# Form Submit double popup message JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return valider()" method="post">
```

I think here is my problem,

I removed my form because it was too long, but i think it is fine

```
            <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" onclick="valider()"/>
```

I think this is my problem and above too

```
            <script>
                function valider() {

                    var mes = "";
                    var prenom = document.getElementById("prenom").value;
                    var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
                    var adresse = document.getElementById("adresse").value;
                    var adresse2 = document.getElementById("adresse2").value;
                    var ville = document.getElementById("ville").value;
                    var province = document.getElementById("province").value;
                    var codepostal = document.getElementById("codepostal").value;
                    var courriel = document.getElementById("courriel").value;
                    var telephone = document.getElementById("telephone").value;
                    var langue = document.getElementById("langue").value;
                    var pieces = document.getElementById("pieces").value;

                    if (prenom == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Prénom" + " manquant!";
                    }
                    if (nom == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Nom" + " manquant!";
                    }
                    if (adresse == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Adresse" + " manquante!";
                    }
                    if (ville == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Ville" + " manquante!";
                    }
                    if (province == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Province" + " manquante!";
                    }
                    if (codepostal == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Code Postal" + " manquant!";
                    }
                    if (courriel == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Courriel" + " manquant!";
                    }
                    if (langue == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Langue" + " manquante!";
                    }
                    if (pieces == "") {
                        mes = mes + "\n" + "Pieces" + " manquantes!";
                    }
                    if (mes != "") {
                        alert(mes);
                    }

                    else {
                        var txt;
                        var r = confirm("Veuillez confirmer: \n" + "\n" + "Prénom: " + prenom + " \n Nom: " + nom + "\n Adresse: " + adresse + "\n Ville:" + ville + "\n Province: " + province + "\n Code Postale: " + codepostal + "\n Courriel: " + courriel + "\n Langue: " + langue + "\n Montant mensuel dépensé: " + pieces);
                        if (r == true) {
                            window.location = "remerciment.html";
                        }
                    }
                }

                function delayer() {
                    window.location = "remerciment.html"
                }

            </script>
            <input type="reset" value="Effacer" />
        </form>
```

i created a form within a table to align my text, created different variables to check if the fields are completed, i know that i could have used required but we need to have a popup stating the invalid fields
I know where my probably is, its the onsubmit and the onclick i invoke twice the function valider but whenever i remove one it doesnt redirect me to the other page neither does the popup appears

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: When i submit with nothing in my form, there is a popup with the missing fields and then when i press OK, the same popup pops again. I think its because i invoke twice my function, once in my form and once in my submit button

Comment: Yes, that is obviously why it's not working.

Comment: Yes but i tried removing one of them but i wouldnt redirect me to the other page and the confirmation popup wouldnt appear http://jsfiddle.net/ch7x9sLk/ i updated the link, i only receive 2 popups whenever the fields are empty

Comment: I don't see ur issue as i removed valider() call from onclick of submit button. http://jsfiddle.net/ch7x9sLk/5/

Comment: The popup appears with the confirmation but it doesnt redirect to the other page